# ¿Cuando construyo una pagina desde el administrador de wordpress, que archivo se encarga de construir dicha pagina?

Tags: php, wordpress

Si voy al administrador de wordpress (paginas- añadir nueva) en que archivo queda guardado el código que se encarga de construir dicha pagina?

Comment: las paginas estan en las db.. estasn preguntando por el codigo del insert???

Comment: no se como expresar bien la pregunta, por ejemplo yo construyo un archivo singular.php que se encarga de construir como se debe mostrar la pagina donde se lee cada post y se en que parte esta este archivo, sin embargo si voy al administrador "paginas- añadir nueva" y le coloco un titulo y un texto, donde esta el codigo que se encarga de construir la pagina de esa manera (como las paginas de ejemplo que vienen con los temas de wordpress)

Comment: las paginas esas no son archivos php. Son entradas en la base de datos, que se terminan mostrando como paginas.

Comment: disculpas si mi pregunta el de novato, pero me puedes decir donde esta el codigo que hace los llamados a la db, para que finalmente se muestre le info?

Comment: No conozco a fondo el codigo de WP, pero es libre, y esta explicado en sus manuales. Deberias revisarlos.

Comment: tanto el código que almacena la página en la base de datos como el que lee de la BBDD están en alguna parte de `wp-includes`. No sé en cual, pero en general no se necesita tocar esos archivos. Se supone que todo lo que quieras hacer para modificar el cómo se ve un post o una página puedes hacerlo en tu theme usando los hooks nativos

Comment: Tu pregunta, cuyo núcleo es: *en que archivo queda guardado el código que se encarga de construir dicha pagina*, no es real en su planteamiento mismo, porque el código que se encarga de construir una página no queda guardado en el momento en que creas la página (o el post, porque WP tiene dos tipos de publicaciones), lo que queda guardado en ese momento es el contenido en la B. de Datos. WP es un CMS que usa un conjunto de archivos para mostrar/gestionar ese contenido. Dichos archivos, que se encuentran en distintas carpetas, se crean cuando instalas WP por 1ª vez y son siempre los mismos...

Comment: ... es difícil (aunque no imposible) saber exactamente qué archivos son usados cuando creas una página. De cualquier modo, saber cuáles son esos archivos no tiene ningún interés, la razón es muy simple: **esos archivos no se tocan**, so pena de dejar tu WP inservible o peor aún, de hacer tu sitio vulnerable. Si lo que pretendes es personalizar algo WP tiene formas muy concretas de hacerlo. Sólo como ejemplo, [si observas aquí](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/#related) verás la cantidad de archivos que pueden invocar a una sola de las miles de funciones de WP...

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es modificar las plantillas que utiliza wordpress para mostrar las páginas, la recomendación es que estudies el codigo de page.php, pero si lo que quieres es crear una plantilla propia puedes empezar modificando algun template.
En TwentySeventeen están en la carpeta: template-parts.
No puedo ayudarte más con los detalles que nos compartes.